# Get the value of URL Parameters in WKWebView and create new URL

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipados

I'm trying to get the current URL of the WKWebView, search/copy one value out of it, and create a new URL.

I use Swift and have this an URL like that  `https://example.org/bundle-572974a2.html` and try to get the following value `572974a2`.
My intention is to create a new URL with that value. The numbers can change from time to time.

I use this code to get the current WKWebView URL. I think I have to convert this to a string first.

```
let oldURL = webView.url
```

And I use this code to create my new URL.

```
var components = URLComponents()
        components.scheme = "https"
        components.host = "new-example.org"
        components.path = "/g"

        components.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "newbundle", value: "XXXXXXXX")
        ]
        
        let newURL = components.url
```

How can I change/paste the `value: "XXXXXXXX"` with the value `572974a2` of the old URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some simple URL manipulation and string handling will get you the number from the old URL:

```
let oldURL = URL(string: "https://example.org/bundle-572974a2.html")! // An example
let name = oldURL.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent // bundle-572974a2
let number = name.dropFirst(7) // remove "bundle-"
```

This assumes the number will always be preceded by "bundle-" (or any seven-letter sequence really. If that can vary then the use of `dropFirst(7)` will need to be replaced with code that can handle strings like "bundle-572974a2" and remove the part you don't want.

Then building the new URL becomes:

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "new-example.org"
components.path = "/g"

components.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "newbundle", value: String(number))
]
        
let newURL = components.url
```

---

In a case where you might have both a prefix and a suffix you need to remove, the following would be one way to remove them. This code assumes there will be a prefix to remove if there is a suffix to remove. If there is a suffix and no prefix to remove then this code gives the wrong result.

```
var number = url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
if let hyphen = number.firstIndex(of: "-") {
    number = String(number[number.index(after: hyphen)...])
}
if let hyphen = number.lastIndex(of: "-") {
    number = String(number[..<hyphen])
}
```

P.S. String manipulation in Swift is a pain.

Comment: Thank you @HangarRash That works perfectly! Just out of curiosity, how should I replace the code, if the URL is sometimes `bundle-572974a2-1484` and I'm still looking for the `572974a2`. I guess the easiest should be an if, then code? If the string is longer than 15 characters, then remove the additional last character?

Comment: I updated my answer with code that can handle having just a suffix or both a suffix and prefix that need to be removed. And of course it handles there being neither to remove.

Comment: String manipulation is a lot better in Swift 5.7 / iOS 16 than it was before. You might want to learn about the improvements.

Comment: @matt I just scanned the String chapter of the Swift 5.7 book and I don't see anything different. I'll keep looking. Though if you have one specific example to point out that may help in my search. Thanks.